# Как оптимизировать программу по памяти?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, графы

Решаю задачу для контеста Яндекса, вылетает на одном тесте, пишет Memory Limited. Пытался делать решение через списки, но так получается что программа тратит еще больше памяти.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
conf_num = int(input())

conf_dict = {}
conf_list = []
m = 1

for i in range(conf_num):
    conf = input()
    conf_list.append(conf)
    
    for s in range(len(conf) - 2):
        if conf[s:s + 3] not in conf_dict:
            conf_dict[conf[s:s + 3]] = m
            m += 1


    
conf_table = [[0] * len(conf_dict) for i in range(len(conf_dict))]

pairs_list = []
edge_num = 0

for i in conf_list:
    for s in range(len(i) - 3):
        conf_table[conf_dict[i[s:s + 3]] - 1][conf_dict[i[s + 1:s + 4]] - 1] += 1
        
        if [i[s:s + 3], i[s + 1:s + 4]] not in pairs_list:
            pairs_list.append([i[s:s + 3], i[s + 1:s + 4]])
        
        if conf_table[conf_dict[i[s:s + 3]] - 1][conf_dict[i[s + 1:s + 4]] - 1] == 1:
            edge_num += 1

# ВЫВОД

print(len(conf_dict)) # Кол-во вершин графа

print(edge_num) # Кол-во ребер графа

for i in pairs_list:
    print(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {conf_table[conf_dict[i[0]] - 1][conf_dict[i[1]] - 1]}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заметьте, что существует максимум `456976=26^4` рёбер, поскольку каждое ребро соответствует комбинации `S[i]S[i+1]S[i+2]S[i+3]` четырех латинских символов, и при использовании ребра в качестве ключа, памяти требуется всего несколько мегабайт (можно ещё уменьшить, сопоставив последовательности символов число в указанном диапазоне, но и так пройти должно)

Можно сделать всего один проход по строкам, беря 4 символа за раз

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'abcdcdcdabcd'

e = Counter()
for i in range(len(s) - 3):
    t = s[i:i+4]
    e[t] += 1

for item in e:
    print(item[:3], item[1:], e[item])

abc bcd 2
bcd cdc 1
cdc dcd 2
dcd cdc 1
dcd cda 1
cda dab 1
dab abc 1
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, но вопрос, как в таком случае найти количество вершин графа?

Comment: ещё set добавьте, в который по ходу дела складывайте трехбуквенные последовательности